# Meu data está correto?

Tags: jquery

Tenho dúvidas se estou passando corretamente os dados pelo data, a sintaxe está correta? Estou enviando para o recebedor.php e tentando pegar com POST['imagemdomeumodelo']; e não funciona.

```
$('#novo').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    form = document.getElementById('novo');
    var data = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajaxDoEnvioDeEmail.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{'imagemdomeumodelo':data},
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(msg) {

            console.log(msg);
            $('.envios').show();
            $('.envios').html(msg);

        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.divtop').hide('fast');
            $('.carregando').fadeIn('slow');    

        },
        complete:function() {
            $('.carregando').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.sucesso').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.envios').show();
            $('.sucessow').fadeIn('fast');
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Em vez de `data:{'imagemdomeumodelo':data}` faça assim `data: data`

Comment: Mas eu quero enviar mais outras informações , tipo data:data+outraVariavelComNamesDoFormularioHtml

Comment: Como fazer isso?

Comment: Podes fazer assim, como você criou a variável `data` e o valor dela é a interface `FormData` você pode usar o método `append`, veja: `data.append('nome', 'Fulano de Tal');`, fazendo assim, será adicionado no valor da variável `data` como se o que você colocou estivesse como um elemento do formulário.

Comment: Se você quer postar um objeto no seu atributo, eu acho que você vai precisar serializa-lo antes (dê uma olhada nisso: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

Comment: Wm Souza obrigado, mas eu optei por outra solução, coloquei um input hidden e peguei saca?

Comment: append serve pra adicionar elemento html né? Como é ele?

Comment: $( ".container" ).append( $( "h2" ) ); Ja pesquisei aqui, no caso nessa situação eu tou adicionando um h2 dentro de uma div chamada containter.

Comment: Existe diversos `append`, um deles é o que você citou, usado no jQuery, esse que eu disse é especificamente da interface `FormData`, veja a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData) em **Português**. Você pode também usar assim: `data.append('nome', $('nome_do_campo_html').val());`